# image_picker: compressing is not supported for type (null). Returning the image with original quality

Tags: image, flutter, dart, picker

I want to change the image quality for picked image, but I got this error. Does anyone know how to fix this?
(I got an image from iOS device.)

`image_picker: compressing is not supported for type (null). Returning the image with original quality`

```
Future getImageFromCam() async {
    File image;
    try {
      image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 90);
    } on Exception {
      _showDialog(context);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to source code, compress image only support JPEG
and according to this discussion https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8319465

```
All photos taken with the camera will be JPG, unless you go to Settings/Camera - Formats and choose High Efficiency. But High Efficiency will make the photos HEIF,
```

So you can check your camera setting with this reference
https://www.mactrast.com/2017/10/set-iphones-camera-back-saving-photos-jpeg-ios-11/

IOS part

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerMetaDataUtil.m

```
(NSData *)convertImage:(UIImage *)image
               usingType:(FLTImagePickerMIMEType)type
                 quality:(nullable NSNumber *)quality {
  if (quality && type != FLTImagePickerMIMETypeJPEG) {
    NSLog(@"image_picker: compressing is not supported for type %@. Returning the image with "
          @"original quality",
          [FLTImagePickerMetaDataUtil imageTypeSuffixFromType:type]);
  }
```

Dart part https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/lib/image_picker.dart

```
 /// The `imageQuality` argument modifies the quality of the image, ranging from 0-100
  /// where 100 is the original/max quality. If `imageQuality` is null, the image with
  /// the original quality will be returned. Compression is only supportted for certain
  /// image types such as JPEG. If compression is not supported for the image that is picked,
  /// an warning message will be logged.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I figured out!

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on what you did to fix the error?