# error image_picker: compressing is not supported for type (null). Returning the image with original quality

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I want to get picture by [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker), but my project apper error.
Please tell me the solution.

error↓

```
image_picker: compressing is not supported for type (null). Returning the image with original quality
flutter: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/~~~~/tmp/image_picker_~~~~.jpg
```

myProject code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

File? _image;
final picker = ImagePicker();
XFile? pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

Future _getImage() async {
      setState(() {
        if (pickedFile != null) {
          print("${pickedFile.path}");
          _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        }else{
          print("NO IMAGE");
        }
        _image = File(pickedFile!.path);
      });
    }
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57487168/14715874 , same issue.

Comment: I saw this article. But I didn't know what to do specifically.